# How to use connection object

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website and using php and mysql..
what is the criteria for connection object?
do we have to use different connection object in every page or same connection object for every page whatever be the work

Answer (score 0):

Create a connection class and use it everywhere.

Look at the following articles:

- [PHP MySQL Connection class](http://www.electronicspub.com/articles/articles.print.php?id=19)
- [PHP MySQL Data Connection Class](http://snipplr.com/view/12517/php-mysql-data-connection-class/)